# start activity in FREFunction of air native extension

Tags: air-native-extension

in the native java code of my native extension,i need to jump to a particular page,what i have tried is to start a new Activity in the call function of FREFunction Object,my code is like this:

```
`ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(arg0.getActivity() ,SecondActivity.class);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(comp);
arg0.getActivity().startActivity(intent);`

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
                EditText show = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.show);
                ComponentName componentName = getIntent().getComponent();
    show.setText("组件包名");
}

}
```

from the logcat of ddms,i am sure the SecondActivity class has been executed,but failed at setContentView(R.layout.second);
then what is wrong with my native code, how can i deal with it?can any body help me or give me same advices?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use the R.* shorthand to access resource ID from within an ANE.

I've written a little helper class / function that may be helpful to you:

http://labs.distriqt.com/post/1245

It basically searches the resource packages for your resource.

If you have access to your FREContext instance you can also use the getResourceId function, see the following for more information:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WS39e706a46ad531be-fd70de2132a8f3874e-8000.html#WS39e706a46ad531be-fd70de2132a8f3874e-7fff

Answer (score 0):

before startActivity use getResourceID

```
int layoutID;               

Intent i = new Intent(arg0.getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);

try {
      layoutID = arg0.getResourceId("layout.second");
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.printf("getResourceID() failed with error:\n\"%s\"\n",e.toString());
         Toast.makeText(arg0.getActivity(), "getResourceID() failed" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return null;
      }

System.out.printf( "layout ID: %d\n", layoutID);
Toast.makeText(arg0.getActivity(), "success: layout ID is " + String.valueOf(layoutID),         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

i.putExtra("layoutID", layoutID);
```

Then later you can retrieve the layout ID at onCreate with this:

```
int layoutID = getIntent().getIntExtra("layoutID", -1);
setContentView(layoutID);
```